# Datatable returns No data available in table when the JSON I give it looks valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, datatable

I am trying to initialize data tables and feed it an array of objects. I am getting an error saying that there is `No data available in table`. But I can print it out to the console and see that that is incorrect.

```
//JS

get_notes().done(funciton(){

     console.log(my_json)//what its format is below
     //my_json = [
           {
              "username": "thomas", 
              "fullname": "Thomas familyname"
            }, 
       /*...*/]

       _.isArray(my_json) //true

     $("#note_table").DataTable({
        data: my_json,
        columns: [
            {title: "fullname"},
            {title: "username"}
        ]
     });
});

 <!--HTML-->
 <table id="note_table">

       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>fullname</th>
               <th>username</th>
        </thead>     

        <tobdy>

        </tbody>

 </table>
```

How can I prevent this error?

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest problem is this:

```
columns: [
            {title: "fullname"},
            {title: "username"}
        ]
```

it should be

```
columns: [
                {data: "fullname"},
                {data: "username"}
            ]
```

You also have to make sure your table is properly defined (typo  `<tobdy>`)

Here's a link to a working fiddle for your example:
http://jsfiddle.net/bmartinelle/bjppck3d/1/

Comment: Neat. Thank you! I'll accept as soon as I'm not on mobile.

Comment: When an element is added to the array, why is it put at the top. How can that be avoided? Thanks.

Comment: How do you add it? Can you add your code to my fiddle?

Comment: I don't see any changes?

Comment: what you can do is set an order: http://jsfiddle.net/bmartinelle/bjppck3d/4/
"order": [[ 1, "desc" ]] // you specify the index of the field to sort on as well as the direction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61423/discussion-between-thomas-and-birgit-martinelle).